# How to set the minimum or maximum time value of a java.util.Date?

Tags: java, date

I'd like set a `java.util.Date`-Objekt to its minimum or maximum time values for a Date (one day).
The way I do it currently (for minimum):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(aDate);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
//... same for minutes, seconds, milliseconds
```

But this seems a little bit cumbersome. And how do I set the maximum?

Comment: this is much better than standard api http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Joda time has a class for http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateMidnight.html which is a whole day at midnight.

Comment: removed my answer as I misunderstood the question sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, use JodaTime's DateMidnight class, as others have suggested.

Or if you can't switch to JodaTime, use [`DateUtils.truncate(Date, field)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#truncate%28java.util.Date,%20int%29) and the `DateUtils.addXyz()` methods from [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
Date lastMidnight = DateUtils.truncate(new Date(), Calendar.DATE);
Date endOfToday = DateUtils.addMilliseconds(
                      DateUtils.addDays(lastMidnight, 1), -1);
```

Comment: Cool, as I already have commons-lang in my classpath. But how would I set the maximum?

Comment: @Mulmoth as long as you don't say [Here's your Sign](http://www.snopes.com/humor/jokes/heresign.asp) ... :-)